# Webrtc to remotely control phone camera

Tags: webrtc

I am looking for help to take still photos remotely using webrtc. Is there an API that allows access to the other person's rear camera (with permissions) to take photos and save them to my phone? The idea is to use this to take full resolution photos with Android and iOS using react.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by let them join a channel and then you can send request from your side to ask camera to take picture and then send you back. This is just like message. You sending message from your side to ask other person for taking picture although. If he is using browser then it can be done using js for getting permissions. But in case of a mobile application you can have your own endpoints to interact with channels. I hope you got the basic idea.